# Did Kaguya's cardiologist Dr. Shozo Tanuma have some prior relationship with Nayotake Shimizu (Kaguya Shinomiya's mom)?

Tags: kaguya-sama-love-is-war

The doctor Shozo Tanuma tells a story to Shinomiya saying he once had a lovelife that he totally relates to her. And in the end of Episode 8 he talked to the stars and said "Nayotake Don't worry your daughter is fine.". Well that totally make sense of why Shozo Tanuma became the doctor of the Kaguya's and takes first priority(maybe) to Nayotake's daughter Shinomiya.

Don't know if this was already shown in the manga. So does Shozo Tanuma once had a relationship with Natoyake Kaguya? or just known her for some time?

Comment: It could also imply that because Nayotake Kaguya died of heart disease Shozo Tanuma became a doctor and majored in cardiologist to protect Shinomiya Kaguya with the same disease that killed her mother.

Answer (score 1):

#### Part1. Shozo Tanuma is a personal doctor/cardiologist of the Shinomiya family.

[image]

(Usually you see a GP or the doctor at an emergency department before seeing a specialist eg a cardiologist. So, yeah, to really see a cardiologist right away means this doctor has some relationship to this family. In this case, the relationship is that Tanuma is a personal doctor/cardiologist of this family.)

#### Part2. And thus knows all to well that Nayotake Shimizu died of cardiological/heart-related problems.

[image]

#### Part3. And then in the flashback, well... I'm not too sure. (I had to keep cropping the image because apparently it keeps exceeding the file limit.)

[image]

I thought this scene was showing Shozo's view on Kaguya when Kaguya's mom had just died or something, but I'm not sure about that. I was supposed to use this part as an emotional argument as to why Shozo visits Kaguya right away. But anyway there's the other stuff too.

#### Part4. In [Chapter 252 of the manga](https://kaguyasama-wa-kokurasetai.fandom.com/wiki/Chapter_252) (currently the anime is around Chapter 100 with S03E03),

(minor spoiler)

> 'Dr Tanuma tells Miyuki about the story of Kaguya's mother.'